# Fully-ordered set and transfinite mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ be a *fully-ordered class* and let $P(x)$ be a statement which is either true or false for each element $x\in A$. Suppose that following condition holds:
>
> Ind. If $P(y)$ is true for every $y<x$, then $P(x)$ is true.
>
> Then, $P(x)$ is true for every element $x \in A$.

**Statement:** If $A$ satisfies the above things, then $A$ is *well-ordered*.

I want to prove the statement, but I'm lost.
Suppose A is a fully-ordered set but not well-ordered, and A also satisfies the above things. Since A is not well-ordered, $\exists B\subseteq A$ such that $B$ does not have a least element. I want to show this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Note that you know that there is a non-empty such $B$. What about the statement "$\forall b \in B, x < b$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current form your claim is wrong. What you probably want is:

**Claim 1.** Let $(A; <)$ be a strict, (set-like) linear order (where we allow $A$ to be a class) that is not well-ordered. Then there is some condition $P(x)$ such that if $P(y)$ is true for all $y < x$ then $P(x)$ is true and yet there is some $x \in A$ such that $P(x)$ is false.

In other words: The principle of mathematical induction fails for some property $P$ for $(A; <)$ and moreover $P$ can be chosen to be independent of $(A; <)$.

Proof. Let $P(x)$ be the statement "there is no infinite decreasing sequence $x > x_1 > x_2 > \ldots$.

Since $(A; <)$ is no well-founded we indeed have that $P(x)$ is false for some $x \in A$.

However, suppose that $P(y)$ holds for all $y < x$. I claim that $P(x)$ holds: Suppose not. Then there is some infinite decreasing sequence $x > x_1 > x_2 > \ldots$. But now $(x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ witnesses that $P(x_1)$ fails. Since $x_1 < x$ this is the desired contradiction. Q.E.D.

(Note that 'set-like' may not be necessary - depending on how you define well-orders.)

Comment: You can replace $P(x)$ by "The class $\{y\in A\mid y<x\}$ is well-ordered" and thus eliminate the use of choice in your proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Uhm, forget my previous comment. Your improvement obviously works.

Comment: Water, bridge...

Comment: What does it mean that "$P$ can be chosen to be independent of $(A;{<})$"? It _sounds like_ it would mean that there's a single $P$ that would work both for $(A,{<})$ and $(A,{\prec})$, or even $(B,{\sqsubset})$, but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm There is a first order property $P(x,y)$ such that $P(x,(A;<))$ works for all non-well-founded linear orders $(A; <)$. This kind of uniformity comes up in fine structure all the time and hence my brain seemingly thought it was worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 2):

What you have lost when you give up the well order is that $A$ has a least element.  When there is one, your inductive statement says that $P$ is true of that element as there are no predecessors.  Without that, you could have $P$ false of all the elements.  The inductive statement is still true.  One example would be to take $A$ as the rationals and $P(x)$ to say $x$ is irrational.